# Debugger in PhpStorm: I don't have breakpoint in server.php but debupper detect this file

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

I don't have any breakpoints in `server.php` file (Laravel 8.0) but the debugger detect this file.

I'm using PhpStorm 2022 and Xdebug 3

[image]

Comment: 1) You seems to be using `php artisan serve` or alike command. 2) You may have "Break at first line..." option enabled in PhpStorm settings. Check that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I fix that problem!

you must delete the folder .idea in your folder project and restor to default setting your PhpStorm